# Content-encoding gzip header not recognised in request

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have a standard embedded tomcat REST API application.  I would like clients to send zipped JSON bodies using the header `Content-Encoding: gzip`

Below is an idea of how this might work:

```bash
echo '{"field1":"hello","field2":"there"}' > request.json
gzip request.json

curl -u user:password -H "Content-Encoding: gzip" -H 'Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf8' --data-binary @request.json.gz HTTP://localhost:8100/some/path
```

I noticed (in the docs) support for compressing the response.  I enabled this using `server.compression.enabled: true`.

I get this error (which indicates to me that the binary data is interpreted as a JSON:

```
JSON parse error: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\\r, \\n, \\t) is allowed between tokens; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\\r, \\n, \\t) is allowed between tokens\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
```

How can I tell Spring Boot to uncompress requests with this header?

I guessed `server:http2.enabled: true` would work, but this does not seem to have an effect.  Is `http2` somehow tied to this feature?

Comment: gzip doesn't require http2 and unzipping should be done automatically. afaik the header is `Content-Encoding` (notice the case), the same for `Content-Type`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Are you using tomcat?

Comment: I'm using a variety of servers, but afaik the gzip decompression should be automatically handled. The compression (the response) is the stuff that needs to be turned on.

Comment: I tried with the suggested case on the header names and improved my question a bit by showing the error I get.

Comment: `compression.enabled` doesn't exists it is `server.compression.enabled` but afaik that is for the response not the request. Also have you tried sending the response without gzip just plain to see if it is handled properly before enabling gzip?

Comment: I fixed the text in the question - `server.compression.enabled`; I was following the suggestion: 'The compression (the response) is the stuff that needs to be turned on.` (and I still get the error).

Comment: That wasn't a suggestion but a remark that if you want response compression you need to enable it. Looking at the tomcat sources there is only output zipping, so you probably need an additional gzip filter to unzip it I'm afraid. I was under the impression this should work out-of-the-box... :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246225/discussion-between-willem-and-m-deinum).

Comment: Jetty and Undertow seem to support this out-of-the-box judging from the documentation.